# Provide theme suggestions for menu content items

Tags: theming, hooks

For a mega menu, I'm trying to add theme suggestions to every parent menu item / menu link depending on the chosen view mode for that menu item.

I'm aware of the `MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_menu_link_content_alter()` function but it does not work for me.

Every menu item has a `view mode` field but since I can't use a hook to preprocess it, I cannot create any theme suggestion for menu items .When I try to use the `theme_suggestion` hook on the menu, I can only see items like this: [image: menu items inside from menu hook]

Am I missing something? Is it possible to add theme suggestions to menu items? If so,how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View modes in menu items don't come from core. You are probably using the [Menu Item Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras) module.

You can look at the Menu Item Extras module's code which does what you are asking for in [menu_item_extras.module#L158-184](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/menu_item_extras/-/blob/8.x-2.17/menu_item_extras.module#L158-184).

But to have the suggestions kick in, you maybe need to make your current `menu--MY-MENU.html.twig` print actual menu item `{{ content }}` first.

Alternatively for testing try to remove any prior `menu--MY-MENU.html.twig` to have the `menu--extras.html.twig` kick in and see how the suggestions by view mode appear. You even get one suggestion for the level.

```html
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * menu-link-content--main--1--MY-VIEW-MODE.html.twig
   * menu-link-content--main--1.html.twig
   * menu-link-content--main--menu-level-0--MY-VIEW-MODE.html.twig
   * menu-link-content--main--menu-level-0.html.twig
   * menu-link-content--menu-level-0.html.twig
   * menu-link-content--main--MY-VIEW-MODE.html.twig
   * menu-link-content--main.html.twig
   * menu-link-content--MY-VIEW-MODE.html.twig
   x menu-link-content.html.twig
-->
```